# Elasticsearch upgrade 2.3.1 Nest client Raw String

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

While upgrading to elastic 2.3.1 I am running into a snag with the .Net Nest Client.

In Nest 1.0, I could read an index's settings from a file and configure the index on creation using the raw string. Is there a way to the something similar in Nest 2.0 or do I have to use the fluent API for each setting including the analysis portion? The same question for mappings.

Nest 1.0

```
private bool CreateIndex(string index, FileInfo settingsFile)
{
    var settings = File.ReadAllText(settingsFile.FullName);

    IElasticsearchConnector _elastic
    var response = _elastic.Client.Raw.IndicesCreate(index, settings);

    if (!response.IsValid)
    {
        //Logging error
        return false
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ElasticClient.Raw` has been renamed to `ElasticClient.LowLevel`.

This is how you can compose your request in NEST 2.x.

```
_elastic.Client.LowLevel.IndicesCreate<object>(indexName, File.ReadAllText("index.json"));
```

Content of `index.json` file:

```
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 1,
            "number_of_replicas" : 1
        },
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "analyzer-name" : {
                    "type" : "custom",
                    "tokenizer" : "keyword",
                    "filter" : "lowercase"
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings" : {
            "employeeinfo" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "age" : {
                        "type" : "long"
                    },
                    "experienceInYears" : {
                        "type" : "long"
                    },
                    "name" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "analyzer" : "analyzer-name"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.