# Index JSON string using Elasticsearch NEST bulk API

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

The title says it all. It looks like there was RawClient in NEST that was enabling to do this, but it is deprecated, at least I do not see it in NEST 2.0.
So how can I index Json string using `Bulk` or `IndexMany` in NEST 2.0 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch upgrade 2.3.1 Nest client Raw String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454147/elasticsearch-upgrade-2-3-1-nest-client-raw-string)

Comment: The low level client aka `client.Raw` was renamed to `client.LowLevel` to better reflect what it is